# replace Win 7 starter with Win 7 pro in mini laptop

Tags: windows-7

i have the mini HP laptop (atom 1.6 2G memory)

and i whant to replace my windows 7 starter with windows 7 professional

is it spoil my laptop performance ?

thank's in advance

Comment: Your previous question contained answers to this already (http://superuser.com/questions/96701/what-is-windows-7-starter-edition/96704#96704), the comments under, notably. Is there something else, in particular, that you need to know?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be good, as the minimum specs are the same regardless of the version.

You may run into things running a little slower as there are more features (turned on) in Pro than in Starter, but you can turn most of those additional features off.  Getting more RAM for the netbook would probably help that situation as well.

You can get Specs and the Upgrade Advisor [here](http://www.microsoft.com/windows/windows-7/get/system-requirements.aspx).

You can go abouts getting the upgrade by using the [Windows Anytime Upgrade](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/products/windows-anytime-upgrade) stuff built into Windows 7.