# 32-bit operating system on 64-bit machine with 4 gigabytes of memory or less

Tags: 64-bit, operating-systems, 32-bit

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Other benefits of 64-bit OS apart from memory expansion?](https://superuser.com/questions/9112/other-benefits-of-64-bit-os-apart-from-memory-expansion)

I'm going to be buying a laptop soon.  I'm going to install Linux so that it will dual-boot Windows and Linux.  If it is a 64 bit machine with 4 gigabytes of memory or less, would there be any downsides in installing a 32-bit copy of Linux instead of a 64-bit one?

If it's relevant, I will most likely be installing Xubuntu 12.04.

Answer (score 1):

If you never upgrade the memory beyond that 4GB then the choice is mostly irrelevant.

I would go x64 because it is most future proof.

32 bit is useful if:

- You are really low on memory (think 16MB or 32MB)
- Your CPU only supports 32 bits.